# CustomValidator not being called

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have a CustomValidator that is being used to check username availability, but it isn't getting called (I also checked it with a breakpoint).

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="usernameC" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Username is already taken" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" Display="None" OnServerValidate="usernameC_ServerValidate" />
```

*Code-behind*

```
protected void usernameC_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (new UsersBL().SearchUserByUsername(args.Value) == null)
        args.IsValid = true;
    else
        args.IsValid = false;
}
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: why do you set Display="None". Please set it to static.

Comment: @PraVn I'm using a ValidationSummary control

Comment: You can use `ClientValidationFunction` property of the `CustomValidator` and then write a javascript function to validate it on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be called when the page is being posted to the server. e.g. you have an asp:button and when the user click it the page is sent to the server and before it calls the button_click event it calls the server validation function.

Comment: I understood what the problem was, but is it possible to be called like any other validator (autopostback). It may be impossible due to it being a server side rather than client side.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? you can use javascript to do postback and then get the validation function be called